# JSFiddle: Please us POST request

Tags: javascript, html, anchor, href

I'm trying to test something in JSFiddle but I'm getting the above error.

This is the HTML:

```
<a onclick="populate();return false;" class="populate" href="?hello">Hello</a>
<a onclick="populate();return false;" class="populate" href="?hello">One More</a>
<a onclick="populate();return false;" class="populate" href="?hello">Another One</a>
<a onclick="populate();return false;" class="populate" href="?hello">Another Other One</a>
```

Javascript:

```
function populate(){
        var populate = document.getElementsByClassName('populate');     
        for(var i=0; i < populate.length; i++)
            {
                var item = populate[i];
                item.addEventListener('click', function() {
                    var current = this.getAttribute('href');
                    alert(current);
                }, false);
            }
        return false;
    }
```

[JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/msbodetti/jS5Fb/1/)

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: Fiddle works fine and shows alert (http://jsfiddle.net/jS5Fb/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have a problem in the order of your JavaScripts: If you use inline JavaScript event handlers, make sure that all used functions are defined before!

In your case, the function `populate()` is defined in an `onload` event, so at the time the inline JavaScript is parsed, it is not known to the browser. Just swap the execution of the JavaScript to "No wrap - in <head>" and you'll be fine.

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jS5Fb/5/)

**EDIT** (from my comment)

The alert just works after the second click, because the respective click handlers are assigned inside the `populate()` function, which is only executed after a click.

You could change the assignment, though, like in this [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jS5Fb/6/).

Comment: Yours and Arun's solutions work. But can I ask something that wasn't asked originally, why do you have to double click to show the alert?

Comment: @msbodetti The alert just works after the second click, because the respective click handlers are assigned inside the `populate()` function, which is only executed after a click. You could change the assignment, though, like in this [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jS5Fb/6/).

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining everything thoroughly! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to select `No Wrap in Body` in the second dropdown in the left side panel

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Lj5yr/)

Comment: Thanks your solution works! Why do you have to double click to get the alert triggered?